# Runtime Error 438 in a For Loop checking Userform Control Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with 132 Control objects on it. The user fills out the form, then clicks the Confirm button to run a macro that uses the submitted information to make decisions. Image below.  I wrote an If statement that checks: If no name was entered at the top, then don't run the macro; If no checkboxes were checked, then don't run the macro. I found that the If statement does its job in almost all combinations of checked and unchecked boxes; if it finds any one checkbox checked, then it ends for For Loop and carries on with the macro.

Here is a link to an image of my userform:

[image: userform]

Here is the quality gate If statement, the asterisked** Line is highlighted when I get the error:

```
    Dim cCont As Control
    Dim datacheck As Boolean
    datacheck = False
    If ProductName.Value <> "" Then
        For Each cCont In AddNewPage.Controls
            **If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" And cCont.Value = True Then**
                datacheck = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cCont
    End If

   If datacheck = True Then
     'very long, hopefully unrelated macro
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please name the part, then click at least one" & Chr(13) & "checkbox. These are _
           the parameters to be audited.")
   End If
```

The problem is that if I check only checkboxes from the group of three at the bottom, I get a Runtime Error 438. I do not get an error if I only check boxes from the top group, or if I check boxes from both the top and bottom groups, but not if I only check boxes from the bottom group.

I cannot identify the difference between the checkboxes at the top and the checkboxes at the bottom. The properties all seem to be the same, so I don't know why one checkbox would throw an error and the other would not.

Comment: Do all controls have a `Value` property?

Comment: Yes, as far as I am aware. One by one, I made sure to enter a default False into their property fields. And in a following For Loop of very similar function, I do not get this error.

Comment: Error 438 means `Value` is not a member, so you definitely *do* have controls that don't have a `Value` property. Looking at the screenshot, I see a bunch of `Label` controls - these are prime candidates =)

Comment: Okay, I had not thought of that. That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" And cCont.Value = True Then
> ```

The problem is that VBA's `And` operator isn't *short-circuiting*, so both conditions are systematically evaluated for every `cCont`, which presumably includes `Label` controls that don't have a `Value` property.

You can nest the conditions to achieve the short-circuiting behavior the `AndAlso` operator would have in VB.NET:

```
If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
    'we're looking at a CheckBox control
    If cCont.Value Then
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Just tested it out, and the error does not appear. Thank you! I can accept the answer in 3 minutes. Do you know why it works that way? Or why it works for one checkbox and not the other?

Comment: It works for all checkboxes. You are iterating all controls, and that includes the `Label` controls. `MSForms.Label` does not have a `Value` property.

Comment: Okay, I had not considered the Label Objects as Controls. I suppose then it depended on the order in which it checked the checkboxes as opposed to the Label Objects, and it did not get the error on the top group because the For Loop ended before getting to the Labels.

Comment: I believe the order of iteration would depend on the order in which the controls were added to the form's `Controls` collection, but I don't think that's specified or guaranteed in any way - best make no assumptions.